# How to Prevent from Tapjacking in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to prevent from tapjacking with half covered and fully covered window, Does anyone have any idea? please suggest me

prevent from tapjacking, I tried so many methods but nothing usefull.

in github

```
val view = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).rootView
view.filterTouchesWhenObscured = true
```

someone mentioned these lines work but don't know where should i use this, and someone said in Flutter, not possible for tapjacking, but in native it works well, so please anyone who has any answer gives us

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know how to implement Tapjacking in flutter, can you please help us in this

Comment: Could you give more examples? What is the tapjack ( give an example by more code or images)and what did you try? What is your appointed target. @Vijay

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to implement tapjacking in flutter for overlay tap hacking .Flutter widget does not have
setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(true) property . You need to create a  native bridge to achieve this in flutter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).